# 404: '@angular/src' is not in the npm registry?

Tags: angular

I'm getting several 404 errors displayed my chrome devtools Console when I try to run my .NET website with Angular 2. Most of the console errors seem to have the following root cause:

Not found: package "@angular/src"

Here's 1 url returned in the console that returns the error:

https://npmcdn.com/@angular/src/common_directives

I did a text search in my app and no results are returned for "common_directives" so I'm guessing that this is reference is probably made as a dependency from some other reference. Have you seen this error before?  Any idea how to debug?

I tried:

npm i @angular/src --save

However this returns the following error:

'@angular/src' is not in the npm registry

Comment: `common_directives` is in the @angular/common bundle. I'm guessing your build process might do something bad with file paths so the app thinks it imports dependencies from @angular/src, while it really wants to get them from @angular/common/src

Comment: thanks mateusz that seems like a good guess.  the code was working yesterday but not today so now I need to track down what's happening